# How to extract all the likes from my Facebook pages and add them to my site?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a number of Facebook pages, which I provide with daily content. I also have a website on which I promote my services and now I would like to know if it is possible to make somekind of widget which shows the total amount of likes that all my pages have.

Comment: you can't do this. the like api is very strict. you can use custom component to summarize the likes, but thats only for display, and it looks like you've made it there (what is true).

Comment: you can definitely get the page likes. see my answer. also, there is no defined "like api" ;) - there´s only the graph api, the notifications api, ...

Answer (score 0):

Using Facebook Query Language (FQL) you should be able to do this.

something like

```
SELECT share_count, like_count, comment_count, click_count
FROM link_stat
WHERE url = '$myURL'
```

Should work using PHP.

See     https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/ for more info

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy even without a Facebook app:

```
$pageinfo = file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/' . $pageid);
```

You can even just try it in the browser. $pageinfo will have some info about your page, AND the like count. Of course you can also use CURL for this, but file_get_contents is a one-liner.